# Postings list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, information-retrieval, inverted-index

Hi I need to create a postings dict out of a list of unique words tokenised and processed from multiple files. So the final format of the postings dictionary would be:
{wordid: [0, 1, ...], wordid2:[0, 1, ...]},

I am really struggling with this, the only code I have right now is:

```
    for i in range(len(docids)):
      for word in vocab:
        if word not in postings.keys():
          postings[word] = []
        else:
          postings[word].append(i)
```

this just outputs the dictionary with the term and the docids just repeat each other in strange patterns depending on the number of files I've asked it to index.

**Example input and expected output:**
Doc1 = "hello my name is john", Doc2 = "hi my second name is smith".
This would make a vocab list: ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'john, 'hi', 'second', 'smith'].
 Each word has a *wordid* which is just the index of the word

And a docid: [0, 1]
 (this just counts the documents and is used in creating the postings list to say: word *w* occurs in document *doc*)

The final output of this example would be:

```
postings = {0: [0], 1: [0,1], 2: [0,1], 3: [0,1], 4: [0], 5: [1], 6: [1], 7: [1]}
```

So this dict shows each wordid(index of each word in vocab) and which document(s) it appears in

Also the program as a whole is supposed to be ran from the terminal and giving it the directory and number of files as arguments.

Comment: I didnt understand your question at all... What do you have as input? What are `docids` and `vocab` contains?

Comment: This is an inverted index(information retrieval) question where docid and vocab lists are commonly used, docid is a list containing all the urls and index of the documents being read from. Vocab contains all the words from each documents, with duplicate words taken out.

Comment: It would be helpfull, if you can provide a small example with the given inputs (`docids`, `vocab`, `postings`, ...) and the expected output dictionary for this case.

Comment: Thanks, just added it, hope the problem its more understandable now

Answer (score 0):

Going line by line:

```
for i in range(len(docids)):
```

You're going over the range, but the content of the array is `[0, 1, ..]` and you need to add the docids to the `postings`, not the index of them, so you should go:

```
for docid in docids:
```

Next one:

```
  for word in vocab:
```

Since you want the `wordid` to be its index in vocab and not the actual word itself, you should the range here, or something like this (also, please use a standard indent of 4 in Python, almost everyone else does):

```
    for wordid, word in enumerate(vocab):
```

And then:

```
        if word not in postings.keys():
```

You're looking to add a key if it doesn't exist, or append to it if it does. That's what `defaultdict(list)` is for, so initialise `postings = defaultdict(list)` and you won't need the next couple of lines.

Finally, you need to check if a word is in a document, but you have no check in your code that actually checks if a word is in a document. Since you've already processed the entire set of documents creating `vocab`, it seems wasteful to look for every word individually in every document again.

You should construct your `postings` as you're constructing `vocab`.

If you must do it this way, it makes more sense to iterate over whatever is holding your docs, instead of the docids - but it's hard to provide code that would work because you're not sharing example values of the variables you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what your looking for, I have simplified the problem a bit by using a list of strings, instead of a list of files, but hopefully you get where I'm coming from.

```
# This would be you're list of files
Docs = [
    "Hello my name is John",
    "Hi my second name is Smith"
]

vocab = []
postings = {}
for i,doc in enumerate(Docs):
    # if using files for Docs this is 
    # where you read the text from them
    words = doc.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        if word not in vocab:
            vocab.append(word)
        wordId = vocab.index(word)
        if wordId not in postings:
            postings[wordId] = [i]
        else:
            postings[wordId].append(i)

print(postings)
#{0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1], 3: [0, 1], 
# 4: [0], 5: [1], 6: [1], 7: [1]}
```